# Algolia autocomplete not visible with material input field

Tags: css, autocomplete, algolia, material-components-web

I am using [material web components](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/input-controls/text-field/icon/) in my project, as well as an [algolia autocomplete.js](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js). I have made a search input field where I would like to show the results in an autocomplete dropdown menu. This is the html:

```
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--box mdc-text-field--with-leading-icon">
      <i class="material-icons mdc-text-field__icon" tabindex="0">search</i>
      <input name="q"
             type="text"
             class="mdc-text-field__input search-input-js aa-input-search"
             placeholder="Search for players and videos ..."
             aria-label="Full-Width Text Field">

    </div>
  </form>
```

And this is the css:

```
.algolia-autocomplete {
  display: flex!important;
  flex: auto!important;
  height: 100%;
}
.aa-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: $white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.aa-dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  left: 24px;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu .aa-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu [class^="aa-dataset-"] {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  color: #3c3e42;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aa-suggestion {
  padding: 0 4px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  clear: both;
}
.aa-suggestion span {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.aa-suggestion.aa-cursor {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.aa-suggestion em {
  color: #00bcd4;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.aa-suggestion img {
  float: left;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.aa-suggestion a {
  color: #3c3e42;
}

.aa-suggestions-category {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3c3e42;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
}

.powered-by-algolia {
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.aa-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
.aa-input-search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 12px 28px 12px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; }
.aa-input-search::-webkit-search-decoration, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-cancel-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}
.media {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.media-body {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that the dropdown menu is not visible with the `mdc-text-field--box` if I am not using the box field and I am instead using the normal field then the dropdown menu is visible. How can I fix this so that the dropdown menu is also visible with the `mdc-text-field--box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the CSS in order to override the overflow on `.mdc-text-field--box` and update the pseudo elements.

```
.mdc-text-field--box {
  overflow: visible;
}

.mdc-text-field--box:after, 
.mdc-text-field--box:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can find an example on the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samuel_vllnt/5q3hxmzz/3) also.